# outlook crashes when opening attachments - imgutil.dll

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange-2007, internet-explorer-8, outlook-2003

Have a situation where a group of users are unable to open emails that contain attachments from various users. So far it appears limited to certain users, and is not specific to any one machine. We have multiple terminal servers at this location, and it occurs on each one, and with only a handful of our 50+ users.

The scenario:
Using exchange 2007, outlook 2003, system runs Windows 2003 Server Enterprise, with IE8

1. User recieves email from X with an attachment
2. User goes to open the email (either through the list or preview pane) and it errors out, This is only if the email contains an attachment.
3. If they right click on the message they can save out the attachment and open it fine.
4. emails from the same people without attachments open fine.

I've been working with MS to figure this out, but so far am getting nowhere.

I have disabled and removed antivirus from this system, and the errors continue to occcur even with Outlook in safe mode.

I run a number of server farms and have never run into this one before, seems centered around the imgutil.dll, and as states, MS has no real ideas so far. Wondering if its more related to IE8 than Outlook?

Any suggestions/etc would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,Dan

UPDATED:
After having my helpdesk do some further work with the end-users, it appears the problem is only with attached PDF files. If they attempt to open messages via Outlook with PDF attachments it will crash Outlook. If they open these messages via OWA, it will crash Internet Explorer. The end-user gets no visible errors. Have been working with MS to narrow down and troubleshoot this. Will post any updates I have.

---

```
**The error:**
Event Type: Error
Event Source: Microsoft Office 11
Event Category: None
Event ID: 1000
Date:  9/3/2009
Time:  8:16:20 AM
User:  N/A
Computer: DIVTS2
Description:
Faulting application outlook.exe, version 11.0.8217.0, stamp 480f95d9, faulting module imgutil.dll, version 8.0.6001.18702, stamp 49b3ac96, debug? 0, fault address 0x00006e1e.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
Data:
0000: 41 00 70 00 70 00 6c 00   A.p.p.l.
0008: 69 00 63 00 61 00 74 00   i.c.a.t.
0010: 69 00 6f 00 6e 00 20 00   i.o.n. .
0018: 46 00 61 00 69 00 6c 00   F.a.i.l.
0020: 75 00 72 00 65 00 20 00   u.r.e. .
0028: 20 00 6f 00 75 00 74 00    .o.u.t.
0030: 6c 00 6f 00 6f 00 6b 00   l.o.o.k.
0038: 2e 00 65 00 78 00 65 00   ..e.x.e.
0040: 20 00 31 00 31 00 2e 00    .1.1...
0048: 30 00 2e 00 38 00 32 00   0...8.2.
0050: 31 00 37 00 2e 00 30 00   1.7...0.
0058: 20 00 34 00 38 00 30 00    .4.8.0.
0060: 66 00 39 00 35 00 64 00   f.9.5.d.
0068: 39 00 20 00 69 00 6e 00   9. .i.n.
0070: 20 00 69 00 6d 00 67 00    .i.m.g.
0078: 75 00 74 00 69 00 6c 00   u.t.i.l.
0080: 2e 00 64 00 6c 00 6c 00   ..d.l.l.
0088: 20 00 38 00 2e 00 30 00    .8...0.
0090: 2e 00 36 00 30 00 30 00   ..6.0.0.
0098: 31 00 2e 00 31 00 38 00   1...1.8.
00a0: 37 00 30 00 32 00 20 00   7.0.2. .
00a8: 34 00 39 00 62 00 33 00   4.9.b.3.
00b0: 61 00 63 00 39 00 36 00   a.c.9.6.
00b8: 20 00 66 00 44 00 65 00    .f.D.e.
00c0: 62 00 75 00 67 00 20 00   b.u.g. .
00c8: 30 00 20 00 61 00 74 00   0. .a.t.
00d0: 20 00 6f 00 66 00 66 00    .o.f.f.
00d8: 73 00 65 00 74 00 20 00   s.e.t. .
00e0: 30 00 30 00 30 00 30 00   0.0.0.0.
00e8: 36 00 65 00 31 00 65 00   6.e.1.e.
00f0: 0d 00 0a 00               ....
```

Comment: Is it specific types of attachment, or all file types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after working with MS and the end-users on this issue, it turned out to be a problem with Adobe Acrobat Reader. We took both terminal servers offline, removed Reader 8 and upgraded to Reader 9 - users are reporting back everything is fine now.

Odd problem, hopefully this is helpful if anyone else see's these issues.